# Count comparison in .Net

Tags: c#, .net

I have written a method in c# to get a count of a table, and saves the count in settings properties.

```
public static bool CompareCount(int? currentCount)
{

    Properties.Settings.Default.Count = (int)currentCount;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    if (currentCount < Properties.Settings.Default.Count)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

At first time if the count returned is 20. I will save it in the settings and I shud not compare that wiht the previous count. ON second time I want to compare the current count wiht the previoulsy saved count in settings. The above method should assign the current count for the first time . but on second time it shud compare.

thanks in advance.

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, think about what would happen when you cast the `int?` that's coming in to `int` if the parameter is `null`. It doesn't make sense to use a nullable parameter if you don't do anything with it later on. You should either change the parameter type to `int` or you could do this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Count = currentCount ?? 0;
```

Then, the method will *always* return `true`, as the `if` condition is always `false` - remember you're setting `Properties.Settings.Default.Count` to `currentCount` just two lines above that? So how should it ever be larger than `currentCount`?

You need to define for yourself how to determine "the first time" and "the second time". What's the condition to find out whether the method is run for the first time? For the code below I'll assume that there's some default value for `Properties.Settings.Default.Count` that helps you determine whether the method runs for the first time.

Then, from what you say, your code should look like this:

```
public static bool CompareCount(int? currentCount)
{
    int countValue = currentCount ?? 0;

    if (Properties.Settings.Default.Count == <some default value>)
    {    
        Properties.Settings.Default.Count = (int)currentCount;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
    else
    {
        return currentCount >= Properties.Settings.Default.Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Your explanation is better and clearer than my brief one. In case my one gets lost or ommitted, I strongly suggest the author of the question to either change the `Properties...Count` from `int` to `int?` so the automatic default value is null and it's obvious when the app is launched for the first time, OR to manually set the default value to negative one, so it will be equally easy to detect (although less obvious to some). I think that **rarely** the incoming `currentCount` would be negative ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Ask the current found Count to check if it is equal to the default value (zero, or not found or set your own once not found let say `-1`), so once not found you do not compare otherwise compare the values.

For Example:

```
public static bool CompareCount(int? currentCount)
{
    int foundCount = ReadFoundCountFromProperties;
    if (foundCount != 0)
    {
      Properties.Settings.Default.Count = (int)currentCount;
      Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
      if (currentCount < foundCount)
       return false;

      return true;
}
```

Comment: The condition will be always false right? Because currentCount is assigned to properties before comparing. `Properties.Settings.Default.Count = (int)currentCount`. So `currentCount < Properties.Settings.Default.Count` is always false.

Answer (score 1):

What is your problem in implementing it? You have all the blocks already here at hand. Just reorder them properly.

If the problem is that the "int Count" defined in settings is "0" by default, you can change it i.e. to default to -1 so it obviously will be NOT a Count written before. Or, you can change it to `int?` to have default null..